# How many bytes does the name of a variable take up?

Tags: c++

`char fooishness = 'f';`

It takes 1 byte to store the `f`, but how many does it take to store `fooishness`? Where? How does it scale? I've read [this](http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/), but it doesn't address the space needed for naming.

If I have an array of chars, does it take more storage to address the array than it does to hold the data itself?

Comment: It does take up zero bytes in the finally generated code. If you compile in debug mode, you have to take in account that symbol names maybe stored as c style character literals.

Comment: When you compile your program it is translated by the compiler into machine code. Things that exist in C++ like variable names and type information do not exist in machine code. So these things you are worrying about take up zero space in your compiled program.

Comment: This may be operating system specific. So read [this operating system textbook](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) and perhaps [elf(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html)

Comment: So in debug, `fooishness` would be stored as a string?

Comment: This will depend on several factors, first your architecture CPU, Chipsets, ISA, etc., your operating system with its file structure(s), and finally the compiler that you are using. 

If you compile under GCC versus Clang versus MSVC versus Intel compilers, the table look up, naming convention, symbols, etc. will vary!!!

Comment: It may be a string, but it might not be in the program. Some tools store debugger helper information in a separate file.

Comment: @KelsonRumak The C++ language says nothing about the size of compiled objects. That's implementation and platform dependent. If you are curious about a particular combination of those, look at the generated assembler and/or machine code, see one example [here](https://godbolt.org/z/br8aWr).

Answer (score 6):

Names are ephemeral to a C++ program: it doesn't matter how you name things, the executed code [mostly] remains the same. There are few exceptions where nature of the name actually does enter into the observable behavior of a program, e.g., when using `std::type_info()` as that does provides access to an entity which somewhat resembles the type's name.

While names do not affect the size of program entities stored, whether they are on the heap, the stack, global memory, or embedded within other objects names may have a size effect on the program itself: the names used for various entities are stored with debug information which often (but not necessarily) contributes the size of the program run. Also, names of externally referenced entities may end up being used for linker symbols, especially when using any form of shared objects, to resolve what these things refer to. However, in all of these cases the names are a constant size somehow affecting the program size.

Answer (score 1):

**Zero**.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    char fooishness = 'f';
    std::cout << fooishness << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled executable **61,376 bytes**

```
    #include <iostream>

int main() {
    char fooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishness = 'f';
    std::cout << fooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishnessfooishness << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled executable **61,376 bytes**